# Template is not saving Image to database

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I am developing a website that allows users to upload projects with various details such as name, description, image, and deadline. However, I am facing an issue where, upon clicking the "Save Project" button, i get redirected to the homepage, but the image does not get saved in the database while everything else does. No error message is displayed. The problem may lie in the form and script sections since it has been able to save image, but after making adjustments to the form and adding script code, to make it look nicer, it stopped working.

Screenshot of input form: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUVrC.png)

Screenshot of homepage after saving a project: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrb0o.png)

Here is my code:

form that was able to save images:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="{{ project_form.project_name.id_for_label }}">Project name:</label>
    {{ project_form.project_name }}
    <br>
    <label for="{{ project_form.project_description.id_for_label }}">Project description:</label>
    {{ project_form.project_description }}
    <br>
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
    <div class="formset-row">
        {{ form.id }}
        {{ form.image }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    <label for="{{ project_form.deadline.id_for_label }}">Deadline:</label>
    {{ project_form.deadline }}
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Save Project</button>
</form>
```

In models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True,)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name

class Image(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_images')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

In forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Project, Image

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_name', 'project_description', 'deadline']
        widgets = {
            'deadline': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }

ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Project, Image, fields=('image',), extra=5, can_delete=True,)
```

In views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import Project
from .forms import ProjectForm, ImageFormSet

def homepage(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {
        'projects': projects,
    }
    return render(request, 'project.html', context)

def create_project(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        project_form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if project_form.is_valid():
            project = project_form.save()
            formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=project)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
    else:
        project_form = ProjectForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet()

    context = {
        'project_form': project_form,
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'create_project.html', context)
```

In create_project.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create Project</title>
    <style>
        #image-container {
            border: 2px dashed #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #image-container:before {
            content: 'Click to Add Image';
            display: block;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            color: #999;
        }

        .uploaded-image {
            max-width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .delete-image-btn {
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .delete-image-container {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create Project</h1>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="{{ project_form.project_name.id_for_label }}">Project name:</label>
        {{ project_form.project_name }}
        <br>
        <label for="{{ project_form.project_description.id_for_label }}">Project description:</label>
        {{ project_form.project_description }}
        <br>
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        <input type="file" id="image-input" style="display: none;" multiple>
        <div id="image-container"></div>
        <br>
        <label for="{{ project_form.deadline.id_for_label }}">Deadline:</label>
        {{ project_form.deadline }}
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Save Project</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
            const imageInput = document.getElementById('image-input');
            const MAX_IMAGES = 5;
            const MAX_IMAGE_SIZE_MB = 5;

            let imageCount = 0;

            imageContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                if (event.target.className === 'delete-image-btn') {
                    const imageRow = event.target.parentNode;
                    imageRow.remove();
                    imageCount--;
                }
            });

            imageContainer.addEventListener('click', () => {
                if (imageCount >= MAX_IMAGES) {
                    alert('Maximum number of images reached.');
                    return;
                }

                imageInput.click();
            });

            imageInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                const files = event.target.files;
                for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    const file = files[i];
                    if (file.size > MAX_IMAGE_SIZE_MB * 1024 * 1024) {
                        alert(`Maximum image size exceeded. Please select images up to ${MAX_IMAGE_SIZE_MB} MB.`);
                        continue;
                    }

                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = (e) => {
                        const imageUrl = e.target.result;
                        const newImageRow = document.createElement('div');
                        newImageRow.className = 'image-row';

                        const newImage = document.createElement('img');
                        newImage.src = imageUrl;
                        newImage.className = 'uploaded-image';
                        newImageRow.appendChild(newImage);

                        const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
                        deleteBtn.type = 'button';
                        deleteBtn.className = 'delete-image-btn';
                        deleteBtn.textContent = 'Delete or Change Image';
                        newImageRow.appendChild(deleteBtn);

                        imageContainer.appendChild(newImageRow);
                        imageCount++;
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

                    if (imageCount >= MAX_IMAGES) {
                        imageContainer.textContent = 'Maximum Images Reached';
                        imageInput.style.display = 'none';
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Reset file input
                imageInput.value = '';
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

In urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('projekte.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
And in urls.py again:

from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='index'),
    path('delete_picture/<int:project_id>/', views.delete_picture, name='delete_picture'),
    path('edit_project/<int:project_id>/', views.edit_project, name='edit_project'),
    path('delete_project/<int:project_id>/', views.delete_project, name='delete_project'),
    path('create_project', views.create_project, name='create_project'),

]
```